# Excel MOD function is not working

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was doing an exercise with the RSA encryption scheme with small numbers in Excel.  I went to use the MOD function, but it just isn't working at all.

Trying a basic MOD example, I typed the following in to a fresh Excel book:

```
=MOD(2,3)
```

This results in the following:

[image]

I installed LibreOffice as a sanity check and entered the same function and it correctly returned 2.

Am I going crazy here or is my Excel broken?

I think Excel might not be parsing commas correctly, as the UI doesn't indicate that I am moving from one argument to the next.  But I am not sure how to fix it.

EDIT:  As per one of the answers to the question, I attempted to use the Formula interface to execute a MOD function.  The results imply that my Excel is broken in some way.

[image]

EDIT 2:  This is what happens when I click OK on the previous image (but I used 6 and 4 instead of 4 and 3).
[image]

Comment: What is RSA and how is it significant for the question?

Comment: RSA encryption scheme.  I like adding a little context to my questions, but that is just one sentence of context.  I will make that a bit clearer.

Comment: (1) What version of Excel are you using?  (2) You say that you have the same problem with “AND” as you do with “MOD”, so I’ll assume that other functions (e.g., `MAX`, `MIN` and `SUM`) are similarly non-functional. How about simple formulas like `=2+3` and `=4-3`?  (3) Are you using a language or keyboard layout other than US/English?

Comment: Perhaps your system list separator is a semicolon or some other character.

Comment: @Scott Looks like some flavour of Office 365, given that the AutoSave slider is visible at the top left.

Comment: Can you screenshot what happens after you confirm the functions dialog with OK? The second argument has not yet been reflected in the formula bar, so your screenshot shows nothing wrong. What exactly is the "similar result" that you get with AND()? With such a specific problem, you need to provide specific details, not just saying that "weird things happened". Show what these weird things are.

Comment: @Scott (1) I am using 365 ProPlus. (2) Yes, they all fail in the same way.  But I can say things like =MAX(A1:A4).  I am almost certain that the issue is with the comma. (3) No, but I believe I have in the past.  I am currently working with the standard keyboard.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I think the issue is that my Excel doesn't know about or have a list separator.  If you look at the second image in the question and the answer from teylyn, teylyn's attempt created a complete function in the cell.  Mine did not and stopped when there is supposed to be a separator.

Comment: @teylyn When I clicked OK, it told me that I entered too few arguments.  The weird thing is that I have basically never used Excel to do anything complicated on this machine, so I never changed any settings.  I'm thinking I that it's broken and I should just reinstall it, but it is stupidly bundled with my Word and other programs which I don't want to lose my settings on.  Fun fact, Excel wouldn't close until I got rid of the partial function.

Comment: Thank you all for pushing me in the right direction, I figured it out.  I am writing an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has to do with list separators.  For some reason, my machine had the tab character \t as the list separator.  I have no idea how this happened and I certainly don't remember doing it.

I went in to the Control Panel -> Region -> Additional Settings.  Then I changed it to comma and all is well!

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: I do think that Excel should have told me that this was the problem when I used the formula dialog box, but the problem as a whole was not Excel's fault.  Except that it uses operating system settings for this instead of it being a setting in Excel's options.  Honestly, this should be adjustable on a per excel save file basis in case I ever come across a spreadsheet that uses semi-colon.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. I have passed the question to the Microsoft Excel team. I think the behaviour you experienced is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

To get to the root of the problem, start in a blank cell, then click the Formulas ribbon, **Math & Trig** dropdown and select the MOD() function. Fill in the number and the divisor and look at the formula that Excel puts in the formula bar.

That will be the syntax you need to use. Confirm the dialog and compare the formula with the one you entered manually.

If you get an error after confirming this dialog, then there is a more serious problem.

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but weird things happened.  I edited the original question with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using VBA:

Originally even
XLMod = (a - (b * Int(a / b)))
was giving me incorrect results so..

```
Function XLMod(a, b As Long)
' This replicates the Excel MOD function - the VBA mod function returns an integer
'see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378047/vba-equivalent-to-excels-mod-function
 Dim templong As Long

   templong = (b * Int(a / b))
   XLMod = (a - templong)
 End Function
```

I'm not sure why but maybe forcing the first part of the equation possibly eliminates the floating point errors

Comment: This seems unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general problem with functions that take comma as separator between parameters.
If the locale is set to a region that uses comma as decimal symbol, MOD function ceases to run correctly and throws syntax error.
This is true even if a space is inserted after comma like in MOD(3, 2), the error is still present.
The work-around is to temporary change the locale to English US, but we need a definitive fix.

Comment: Yes, a comma might not be the best universal solution, but perhaps the setting should be localized to the excel file rather than to the computer as a whole.  If I have crazy settings, I should be able to still take my excel and use it on another computer.  Any default (which I do not believe I changed) should also work out of the box.

Comment: Note that my computer was configured to not use the comma as a function delimiter nor was it used as a decimal symbol, it was configured to use tab as a function delimiter and period as a decimal delimiter.  Using tab as a delimiter is an illegal operation in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

My answer was that MOD does not exists in a different language version of Excel (Dutch). They use "REST"..

That's why I always install English versions of programs. Unless, like now, my company decides not to..

It seems for you it's English, so that can't be the problem. So maybe this answer helps for someone else so I'm gonna leave it here :)

Translations for Excel you can find here:
https://nl.excelfunctions.eu/MOD/Nederlands